# PP IPN doesn't update my database(PHP)

Tags: database, paypal-ipn

First of all I'd like to say that I'm completely lost when it comes to these things so I most likely have to be spoonfed.

Anyway, I'm using the PP IPN right now so people on my upcoming project can upgrade themselves to "Premium" which will give them some extra functions and such. However, the script works in some way, but it doesn't update my Database information.

In my database I have a field called "vip" which is set to "0" when signing up. If you buy premium it should change to "1". My problem is that it doesn't update the information, even though the payment goes through.

I'm on a live webserver as well.
I've followed a tutorial made by PHPAcademy for this, so again, I'm clueless. And their forum seems rather dead atm.

ipn.php

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
// Read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// Assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$user_id = $_POST['custom']; // Our user's ID

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fps, 1024);

            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                if ($payment_status == 'Completed') { 

                    $txn_id_check = mysql_query("SELECT `txn_id` FROM `log` WHERE `txn_id` = '".$txn_id."'");
                    if (mysql_num_rows($txn_id_check) !=1) {
                        if ($receiver_email == 'h1f5gaming@gmail.com') {
                            if ($payment_amount == '0.01' && $payment_currency == 'EUR') {
                                // add txn_id to database
                                $log_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `log` VALUES ('','".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."') ") or die(mysql_error());

                                // update premium to 1
                                $update_vip = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET vip='1' WHERE `user_id` = '".$user_id."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 


            } else if(strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                // Log for manual investigation
            }
        }
        fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

As you can see I also have "or die(mysql_error())" on two lines at the query but I'd like to say that It's just for testing purposes. It doesn't give me any errors at all.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="h1f5gaming@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Premium Membership">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EU">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.h1f5.eu/thanks.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.h1f5.eu/">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.h1f5.eu/ipn.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Upgrade to Premium" />
</form>
```

Thank you in advance.